# How do i install a package manager to chromeos?

Tags: package-management, chrome-book, chrome-os

I have a rooted x86 chromebook that I want to install Linux packages to. It has no package manager in it so how would I go about installing one? I have tried `crew` but it doesn't have the packages I need.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You may want to edit your question to indicate _what_ packages you need to install.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but answering anyway.

To get a package manager you need to install Linux.  All Chromebooks newer than 2019 have Linux built in.  Just enable it in the Settings.  If your Chromebook is from about 2017 to 2019, it might or might not have that feature:

https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/chrome-os-systems-supporting-linux/

If yours doesn't have Linux, install Crouton:

https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton

Once Linux is installed you'll have the apt package manager.  Google on how to use it.